# Junit + UrlDecoder: Why does this test fail?

Tags: java, junit, urldecode

I have the following code in one of my tests. The second assertion fails.

```
String decode1 = URLDecoder.decode("a%20b", "UTF-8");

assertTrue("a b".equals(decode1)); // pass
assertEquals("a‌ b", decode1); // FAIL
```

I can't figure out why. Is this a bug with JUnit? You would think that JUnit would just call .equals() if the first arg is not null...

Comment: There is a non printing character in your second "a b" String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I pasted your code into a new test, it fails as you stated. However, after deleting the final "a b" string and retyping it, it passed. You must have some embedded characters in there that I don't see when viewing the source of this page.

The failed assertion shows this somewhat by saying the expected value is

```
"a[ ]b"
```

Answer (score 0):

It does call equals().  Looking at the [source code from kickjava](http://kickjava.com/src/junit/framework/Assert.java.htm#ixzz1sd5070Kv), we have the following.  (You didn't say if you are using JUnit 3.8 or 4.0, but I'm pretty sure they didn't change the implementation of something this basic.

```
public static void assertEquals(String   msg, Object   obj1, Object   obj2) {

        if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null) {
          return;
        }

        if (obj1 != null && obj1.equals(obj2)) {
          return;
        }

        fail(msg + " expected=" + obj1 + " actual=" + obj2);
}
```

Are you 100% sure a stray encoded character didn't sneak into your test.  Maybe try this to rule it out?

```
String expected = "a b";
assertTrue(expected.equals(decode1)); 
assertEquals(expected, decode1);
```